# How do I call On-Prem hosted Custom Web APIs from Azure Logic Apps?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

How do I call On-Prem hosted Custom Web APIs from Azure Logic Apps?

I have tried Hybrid connections in the Web API or API Apps where you can setup to access On-Prem endpoints, but cannot find the same thing for Logic Apps.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Are they already exposed to internet?

Comment: @TusharJ I can call them from other Azure hosted Web APIs/Web Apps and from the Azure Web Apps I was able to create Hybrid connections and the calls can make it to my on-prem APIs, but for Logic Apps, I dont see the Hybrid connection feature...

Comment: Yes that is something on backlog coming soon...

Comment: Thanks @TusharJ . Any ETA? and also what is the url on the backlogs that are being worked on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom connector of the logic app and select the 'on-premise' option.

[image]